# Clone system call exits after returning from its associated function

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system, gdb, pthreads

I have a clone system call in C which would call a child function, execute the child and then return to the parent to execute some code. The child executes successfully and control returns to the clone statement. The clone statement then crashes and program execution terminates.

My C code is:

```
    void *stack;
    stack=(void *)calloc(1,16384); 
    stack+=16384;
    clone(NewFunc, stack, CLONE_VM|CLONE_FILES, NULL);
            printf ("Control has returned from clone\n");
```

After control returns from my NewFunc function, the program execution stops and control doesn't transfer to the following printf statement. These are my error messages in gdb:

```
(gdb)
clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:117
117             movq    %rax, %rdi
(gdb)
118             call    HIDDEN_JUMPTARGET (_exit)
(gdb)
[Inferior 1 (process 16603) exited normally]
```

Please help in debugging this issue.

Comment: Can you post more of your code.. enough to compile?

Comment: How does `NewFunc()` look? What does it do?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that the parent would actually execute the printf statement while you are debugging the child itself.

Why not just use a fork/wait?